# intro SWF redirect when finished

Tags: html, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs5

Im using adobe flash cs5. The last 5 frames of my animation include the following
     "navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.soldbybillcox.com/tyler/redwirehome.html"),
     "_self");"

This is an attempt to make the flash redirect after it has finished playing!

Im exporting this as a redwirewithsound.swf flie set to AS3.0 Flash player 10.

Now on to the HTMl im using the following code wich includes the code to allow script access!

```
<object

 classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"

 codebase="
 http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0"           
 width="550" height="400" align="middle">

 <param name="movie" value="http://soldbybillcox.com/redwirewithsound.swf">

 <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">

 <embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash"

 pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"

 width="550" height="400" align="middle"

 src="http://soldbybillcox.com/redwirewithsound.swf"

 allowScriptAccess="always"></embed>

 </object>
```

This code does play the video but does not redirect when finished! Im not sure where the problem is

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to the security model for `navigateToUrl`:

> In Flash Player 10 and later running in a browser, using this method programmatically to open a pop-up window may not be successful. Various browsers (and browser configurations) may block pop-up windows at any time; it is not possible to guarantee any pop-up window will appear. However, for the best chance of success, use this method to open a pop-up window only in code that executes as a direct result of a user action (for example, in an event handler for a mouse click or key-press event.)

As per the [Adobe docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html):